# problemas con cliente oc login openshift

Tags: linux, login

Buenas

Estoy tratando de hacer login desde el cliente de openshift (oc.exe) y siempre que lo hago me sale este error:

```
C:\Users\Tomas>oc login
Server [https://localhost:8443]: https://github.com/XXXX/XXXXX
error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value - verify you have pr
ovided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running.
error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Estoy seguro de que la direccion de github es la correcta

No se si les ha pasado una cosa parecida y pueden ayudarme

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El `server` en el login es la dirección de la consola de Openshift, la cual generalmente es `https://console.xxxxxx.openshift.com`